# MYSQL get the first value in JOIN query

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, inner-join

I have 3 tables: A, B and C.

A has AID, B has AID and BID, and C has BID Value and Date.

I need to create a query that returns me AID and the first (according to date) Value from C.

WHAT I've tried:

```
SELECT A.AID, Value FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.AID = B.BID
INNER JOIN C ON C.BID = B.BID GROUP BY A.AID
```

It gives me the last Value and not the first.

Data example:

A:

```
AID: 
1 
2 
3
```

B:

```
AID BID

1   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
3   5
3   6
```

C:

```
BID Value Date
1   15   1.1.1970
1   422  1.1.1992
2   945  1.1.1975
3   149  1.1.1994
3   147  1.1.2015
4   110  1.1.2004
5   142  1.1.2005
```

The output should be:

```
AID  Value
1     15
2     149
3     110
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Ullas I've added data and expected output.

Comment: add to the query SORT BY VALUE desc

Comment: already added. it just sorted the table, not the values i was looking for. By the way, It suppose to be by date and not by value.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have too many records with the same value and value doesn't have any commas, then the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick is probably the easiest way:

```
select b.aid,
       substring_index(group_concat(c.value order by c.date desc), ',' 1) as first_value
from c join
     b
     on c.bid = b.bid
group by b.aid;
```

Larger amounts of data require a more complicated query.  Something like:

```
select b.aid, c.value
from c join
     b
     on c.bid = b.bid
where c.date = (select min(c2.date)
                from c2 join
                     b2
                     on c2.bid = b2.bid
                where b2.aid = b.aid
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

To restrict C to just those rows with the latest (minimum) date you need a subquery that will produce the minimum date, then use that to limit the rows from C

```
SELECT
      A.AID
    , C.Value
FROM A
      INNER JOIN B ON A.AID = B.BID
      INNER JOIN C ON b.bid = c.bid
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  bid
                , MIN(date) AS mindate
            FROM c
            GROUP BY
                  bid
      ) AS m ON c.bid = m.bid
                  AND c.date = m.mindate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS b;

CREATE TABLE b
(aid INT NOT NULL
,bid INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(aid,bid)
);

INSERT INTO b VALUES
(1   ,1),
(1   ,2),
(2   ,3),
(3   ,4),
(3   ,5),
(3   ,6);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS c;

CREATE TABLE c
(bid INT NOT NULL
,value INT NOT NULL
,date DATE
,PRIMARY KEY(bid,date)
);

INSERT INTO c VALUES
(1   ,15   ,'1970-01-01'),
(1   ,422  ,'1992-01-01'),
(2   ,945  ,'1975-01-01'),
(3   ,149  ,'1994-01-01'),
(3   ,147  ,'2015-01-01'),
(4   ,110  ,'2004-01-01'),
(5   ,142  ,'2005-01-01');

SELECT x.aid
     , y.value 
  FROM b x 
  JOIN c y 
    ON y.bid = x.bid 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT b.aid
            , MIN(c.date) min_date 
         FROM b 
         JOIN c 
           ON c.bid = b.bid 
        GROUP 
           BY b.aid
     ) z 
    ON z.min_date = y.date 
   AND z.aid = x.aid;
+-----+-------+
| aid | value |
+-----+-------+
|   1 |    15 |
|   2 |   149 |
|   3 |   110 |
+-----+-------+
```